# PyCharm Debug:Frame are not available,Variables:connected

Tags: python

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

We see the debug stop at the the breakpoint, then

#### problem 1:

I click the console and input 1
[image: 3]

it cost 10 more seconds to execute! so weird!! and no output, so I input 1 in the console again but found:
[image: 4]
no output
[image: 5]

#### problem 2:

I go ahead debug, for example, execute "next line" or step into function or other. My pycharm then sink into a un-responding state like follows:
[image: 6]
you can see it's continue running not stop.

and at the meantime, the frame or variable become follow:
[image: 7]

So strange! It's ok when I run this code, but not ok when debug.

*Note that my python interpreter is on my remote server.*

Comment: Hi. Please share your code as readable format such as using `` or ctrl + k, not a screenshots or image

Comment: Don't ask here. Go to Jetbrains